# NPGSQL with .netCore how to login to schema not just to database

Tags: c#, postgresql

This is my `NPGSQL` connection string

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {     
        "DataAccessPostgreSqlProvider":  "User ID=damienbod;Password=1234;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=damienbod;Pooling=true;"
        }
    }
}
```

taken from here:
https://damienbod.com/2016/01/11/asp-net-5-with-postgresql-and-entity-framework-7/

But I am using `schemas` under my `Postgres` database. How to connect to `idsrv4` schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All schemas live under the same database, so when you connect to it, you have access to all of them. If you want to access a table in the `idsrv4` schema, just qualify its name:

```
SELECT * FROM idsrv4.mytable;
```

If you don't like to qualify all instances of the table name with the schema, you can change the `search_path` variable:

```
SET search_path = 'idsrv4,public';
```

Now for the remainder of this connection, you can just do `SELECT * FROM mytable`. The meaning of `search_path` is that it contains the list of schemas to be searched when unqualified table name is specified. Note `search_path` works on a per connect basis, so would have to set it every time you connect to the database.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I amusing entity framework so I will not write any select statements. I need to set correct connectionString. Is this possible?

Comment: I think I found something after your suggestion. SearchPath="xxx". I will try now

Comment: "ErrorMessage":"42P01: relation \"AspNetUsers\" does not exist"

Comment: @mbrc Did you give the full search path e.g. `SearchPath="idsrv4,public"`. Also, have you tried using the qualified table name e.g. `idsrv4.AspNetUsers` (assuming that `AspNetUsers` is in `idsrv4`).

Comment: @mbrc Did you solve this problem? Were you able to set the schema in the connection string? I also tried SearchPath and got 42P01 not found as well.

Comment: This does not answer the question, the correct response is the one from Manuel Montoya

Answer (score 20):

You can also specify the search path in the connection string:

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {     
    "DataAccessPostgreSqlProvider":  "User ID=damienbod;Password=1234;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=damienbod;Pooling=true;SearchPath=your_search_path;"
    }
}
```